# Force MS Teams to behave as expected

Tags: dock, desktop, spaces, ms-teams, sonoma

When clicking on an open application in the dock, the desktop on which it has an open window is switched to.

This works for any application, including Microsoft applications, **except MS Teams**, and it's driving me crazy.

When clicking the Teams icon, "Microsoft Teams" will appear in the top bar, but the desktop remains the same. I have to click the icon a second time to actually move to the desktop on which the teams window is open.

For new windows (e.g. when clicking 'settings...' from the top bar menu) the behavior is the same: they open on the desktop on which a teams window is already open, without switching to it.

This is annoying when I'm trying to use the keyboard. When using command-tab, the behavior has the same issue, and there is nothing I can do (I think) to force the correct desktop to become active.

So, my question: **is there a way to force the desktop, on which MS Teams has an open window, to become active when the application is switched to** (switched-to either by clicking it in the dock or by command-tab) i.e. to make it behave as any other app?

Comment: Do you have Keyboard Maestro or a similar tool installed?

Comment: I have [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) and [SKHD](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) installed

Comment: I just tried (with Ventura) and couldn't reproduce this, clicking on the Teams icon in the Dock switched to the Desktop running Teams.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I have Sonoma. I think it's probably more likely to be the Teams version that's causing the issue - but clicking on 'Teams' >> 'About microsoft teams' produces no window, so I cannot share that information.

Comment: I just tried on Sonoma, can't reproduce it there either. Version is 1.6.00.24065, it's displayed at the top of the chat window in Teams when you select "About Microsoft Teams".

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have Version 1.6.00.26957. It was last updated on 2023-09-28. I just restarted yabai, and now the behaviour is gone; Teams behaves like any other app. I'll try to see if it returns and how I could try to isolate the cause... thanks for now!